# Remove tailing slash using .htaccess not woking

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My File structure is:

```
/test/
    myfile.php
    .htaccess
```

The codes inside `.htaccess` file are:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) myfile.php?q=$1  [QSA]
```

And inside `myfile.php` the code is:

```
<?php
     var_dump($_GET['q']);
?>
```

So when I'm browsing `http://127.0.1.1/test/aaa/bbb/ccc` I get this output in the browser:

`string(15) "aaa/bbb/bbb/ccc"`, which is perfect.

But when I'm trying to browse `http://127.0.1.1/test/aaa/bbb/ccc/` I got this output which is not expected:

`string(20) "aaa/bbb/ccc/bbb/ccc/"`

**Can anyone please explain why this happening?? I have also tested this on  webserver.**

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior for the `*` operator is to be greedy (it'll match as many characters as possible, which includes any trailing slash).  Try adding a `?` modifier to switch to non-greedy mode:

```
RewriteRule (.*?)/ $1 [QSA]
```

Comment: It's just stopped producing weird link, but still there is a trailing slash. Output is `string(12) "aaa/bbb/ccc/"`

Thanks, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Just changed `.htaccess` file slightly, and the weird thing is back on the stage:

.htaccess file's code:


     `RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /test/

     RewriteRule ^(.*?)/$ $1 [QSA]

     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteRule (.*) myfile.php?q=$1  [QSA]`